# Find occurrences of connecting words in a string with python

Tags: python

I have a text where all the words are tagged with "parts of speech" tags. example of the text here:

> What/NOUN could/VERB happen/VERB next/ADJ ?/PUNCT

I need to find all the occurrences where there is a `/PUNCT` followed by either `NOUN`, `PRON` or `PROPN` - and also count which one occurs the most often.

So one of the answers would appear like this: 
`?/PUNCT What/NOUN` or `./PUNCT What/NOUN`

Further on the word "Deal" appears 6 times, and I need to show this by code.

I am not allowed to use NLTK, only Collections.

Tried several different things, but don't really know what to do here. I think I need to use defaultdict, and then somehow do a while loop, that gives me back a list with the right connectives.

Comment: Using `defaultdict` seems like a good way to start indeed. If you could should us what you have tried, you might be able to really help you instead of living you out with a solution you do not understand :) (if not done yet, take a look at [ask] and the [tour])

Comment: if you have a string like that you can use regex. Please provide the code you have tried so far, then we can tell where you can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test program that does what you want.

It first splits the long string by spaces `' '` which creates a list of word/class elements. The for loop then check if the combination of PUNCT followed by NOUN, PRON, or PROPN occurs and saves that to a list.

The code is as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
string = "What/NOUN could/VERB happen/VERB next/ADJ ?/PUNCT What/NOUN could/VERB happen/VERB next/ADJ ?/PUNCT"
words = string.split(' ')

found = []

for n, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(words[:-1], words[1:])):
    first_class = first.split('/')[1]
    second_class = second.split('/')[1]
    if first_class == 'PUNCT' and second_class in ["NOUN", "PRON", "PROPN"]:
        print(f"Found occurence at data list index {n} and {n+1} with {first_class}, {second_class}")
        found.append(f'{words[n]} {words[n+1]}')
```

To count the words:

```
words_only = [i.split('/')[0] for i in words]
word_counts = Counter(words_only).most_common()
```

Comment: I'm unsure this answers OPs question: 

_I need to find all the occurrences where there is a /PUNCT followed by either NOUN, PRON or PROPN_

Comment: Op is very unclear, this is at least a first stab at answering the question, it can also be used by the op to answer his actual question once he clears that up (as it wil surely use some combination of the above to achieve the task). But I'll update.

Comment: Updated to find the occurrences of /PUNCT followed by either NOUN, PRON or PROPN

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Jurgen, however its not exactly what I'm looking for. I have tried to clearify my question a bit.

Comment: It was 90% there, hope this answers your question. Please remember to like and accept the answer.